# XmlDocument и два корневых элемента

Tags: c#, xml

На входе есть строка, в которой находятся xml данные, по сути два корневых элемента которые записаны один после другого. При попытке загрузить эту строку в `XmlDocument.LoadXml` выдается ошибка -

> Существует несколько корневых элементов

Изменить входную строку я не могу, и для работы мне нужен второй корневой элемент. Единственный выход который вижу - обрезать строку, но возможно есть более красивое решение?

Comment: а если обернуть два корневых элемента в один, добавив в начале строки и в конце <root><root>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если у документа нет пролога, то можно завернуть весь документ в еще один тэг.

Comment: что вы подразумеваете под прологом? у тегов есть `xmlns:xsi` и `xmlns:ns`

Comment: Пролог это  - DTD и различные XML-декларации. Все это идет до корневого документа.

Answer (score 5):

### Первый способ - XmlDocumentFragment

Для того, чтобы загрузить несколько тэгов, можно воспользоваться классом [XmlDocumentFragment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.xmldocumentfragment(v=vs.110).aspx). Создается он через функцию [XmlDocument.CreateDocumentFragment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.xmldocument.createdocumentfragment(v=vs.110).aspx), пример использования можно увидеть в документации на эту функцию.

В Linq2Xml аналогичного понятия не существует, поэтому надо использовать другие способы.

### Второй способ - дописать корень

Можно использовать довольно популярный трюк, когда требующий разбора текст оборачивается в любой тег.

Этот способ требует отсутствия декларации XML или определений DTD.

### Третий способ - через XmlReader

Можно создать XmlReader с настройкой ConformanceLevel.Fragment, передав ему StringReader (в случае когда надо распарсить строку). Для каждого из корневых элементов можно вызвать ReadSubtree, чтобы получить другой XmlReader, который уже можно передать в метод Load:

```
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(str), new XmlReaderSettings { ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment }))
{
  // Пропускаем мусор до начала первого элемента
  while (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Read()) ;

  if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
  {
    using (var subreader = reader.ReadSubtree())
    {
      doc1.Load(subreader); // загрузка первого элемента
    }
    reader.Read(); // Пропуск закрывающего элемента
  }

  // Второй элемент загружается аналогично
}
```